# Command not starting on boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, startup

I'm trying to run this script https://github.com/oblique/create_ap on startup on my RPi with this command: `/usr/bin/screen -dmS ap /usr/bin/create_ap -m nat wlan0 eth0 RaspberryAP ******`, but it doesn't do anything; it works when starting it manually via ssh, but sadly it's not starting on its own with this command. What did I do wrong?

Still, it doesn't start, but according to `/var/log/syslog` it also didn't have any errors

Comment: Where are you trying to start it from?

Comment: @stevieb I'm using the /etc/rc.local file (in the line before `exit 0`)

Comment: Don't add to /etc/rc.local - that gets run at the end of every runlevel (including well before networking is up and going), suggest new script /etc/rc3.d/S99screen instead

Comment: @steve Should I just add the command or use the skeleton?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new startup script instead of adding to /etc/rc.local file.  Doesn't have to be anything complicated.  Example:

```
$ cat >/etc/rc3.d/S99screen
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -dmS ap /usr/bin/create_ap -m nat wlan0 eth0 RaspberryAP ******
^D
$ chmod 755 /etc/rc3.d/S99screen
$
```

And then reboot to test.

Comment: I followed your instructions, but it seems like it's still not doing anything, because I started screen with `-L` (output logging) and still can't find any logfile

Comment: I just updated/upgraded with apt-get (for another reason) and when restarting apache, it seems like it's going through the startup scripts again, because there it tells me `insserv: warning: script is corrupt or invalid: /etc/init.d/../rc3.d/S99create_ap
`

Comment: Oops, sorry, looks like template approach will be needed then.  Take an existing script in /etc/rc3.d/, copy it to S99create_ap and edit to have your screen command in there, together with all the template headers.  If then works I'll revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sadly, that still didn't work; first I tried copying from `### BEGIN INIT INFO` to `### END INIT INFO`, which did nothing, and the I tried copying the whole file (I copied the cron script) and editing it accordingly (I'm still not sure about the `DAEMON` option). Didn't work either